# How to find closest points between two convex hull in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

In part of an Artificial Neural Network matlab code, I want to find nearest points of two convex polygons.

I saw

```
dsearchn(X,T,XI)
```

command's description [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html), but that finds closest points between two sets of points, and polygons (like convexs) have infinites points.

So can you suggest any way/idea?

Notice: I'm using MATLAB 2014a. I have the coordinate of each convex's vertex point.

Comment: There's a function to this this on [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22444-minimum-distance-between-two-polygons) that will do this. As noted in the comments, the complexity of this function is `O(mn)` while the minimum complexity is known to be `O(logm + logn)` (see [Edelsbrunner](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~edels/Papers/1985-J-02-ComputingExtremeDistances.pdf)).

Comment: @beaker yes, I've found this function before you tell and with a little code changing, that gave my answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [This File](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22444-minimum-distance-between-two-polygons) in File Exchange, I've find the solution.

With a little code modification, I have drawn a perpendicular bisector which I wanted. Of course, this way is time consuming.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are not happy with what is provided by [dsearchn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), then, If I were you, I would do one of two following:

- Find Nearest Neighbours on the vertices (for example which vertex of
  polygon A is the NN of a given vertex of polygon B).
- Pick a random point inside polygon A (you may want to compute the
  convex hull of A, but you may skip that and take into account only
  the vertices you know already). That random point is the query. Find
  an NN of that point from the vertices of polygon B.

---

You may want to ask in [Software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)s for more.

---

Edit:

Another approach is this:

Create a representative dataset of polygon A. Set the size of the dataset yourself and fill it with samples of points that lie inside the polygon. Choose them uniformly randomly inside the polygon.

Then take a point of polygon B (either a vertex or a random point inside polygon B) and that's the query point, for which you will seek Nearest Neighbour(s) inside the representative dataset of polygon A.

Of course that's just an approximation, but I can't think of something else now.

Notice that you can of course do the same for polygon B.

Comment: First way isn't my answer - actually I didn't use dsearchn command because I didn't want to find just nearest vertices - I need to exact answer. Second way has same problem. But really thank you for your time @gsamaras.

Comment: @pooriahaddad yeah I know, but I wanted to give it a shot! I updated my answer, hope it helps. By the way, nice question, got my +1!

Comment: Your last suggested approach seems effective. I've found one solution in File Exchange, but your approach seems need to fewer time to solve the problem. You have my +1, Thanks;